# Protobuf-net v2 and large Dictionaries

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, protobuf-net

I have a weird situation happening that I'm not quite understanding.

I have a 'dataset' class that holds various metadata about a monitoring buoy including a list of 'sensors'.

Each current 'sensorstate'.

Each 'sensorstate' has a bit of metadata about it (timestamp, reason for change etc) but most importantly it has a `Dictionary<DateTime,float>` of values.

These sensors generally have upwards of 50k data points (years worth of 15min data readings) and so I wanted to find something that was a bit faster at serialising than the default .NET `BinaryFormatter` and so set up [Protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) which will serialize fantastically fast.

Unfortunately my problem occurs on deserialization when my dictionary of values throws a exception for there already being an item with the same key added and the only way I can get it to deserialise is to enable 'OverwriteList' but I'm a little unsure why when there aren't any duplicate keys (it's a dictionary) when serializing, so why are there duplicate keys when I deserialize? Which also brings up data integrity issues.

Any help in explaining this would be highly appreciated.

(On a side note, when giving ProtoMember attribute ids, do they need to be unique to the class or the whole project? and I'm looking for lossless compression recommendations to use in conjunction with protobuf-net as the files are getting pretty large)

Edit:

I've just put my source up on GitHub and here is the class in question

[SensorState](https://github.com/Technicolour/B3/blob/master/IndiaTango/IndiaTango/Models/SensorState.cs) (Note: it currently has OverwriteList = true in order to have it working for other development)

Here is an example [raw data file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1109527/B3exampleForImport.csv)

I had already tried using the SkipContructor flag but even with it set to true it gets an exception unless OverwriteList is also true for the values dictionary.

Comment: Hi; I've had a brief look at SensorState, but it is not in a "minimal" state where I can actually jump in and reproduce anything (I tried adding more and more files to get it to compile, but without success). I've added a *minimal* example (processing the data provided) below, showing no issues. Can you help me to help you, by providing a minimal *working, reproducible* example that shows the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where I apologize for ever suggesting it had anything to do with code that wasn't my own doing. And while I'm here mad props to the team behind protobuf and Marc Gravell for protobuf-net it's seriously fast.

What was happening was in the [Sensor](https://github.com/Technicolour/B3/blob/master/IndiaTango/IndiaTango/Models/Sensor.cs) class I had some logic to never let a couple of Properties never be null.

```
[ProtoMember(12)]
public SensorState CurrentState
{
    get { return (_currentState == null) ? RawData : _currentState; }
    set { _currentState = value; }
}
```

[Link](https://github.com/Technicolour/B3/blob/d4f944beada9a7e6a1700eae22cc65ecdadbacff/IndiaTango/IndiaTango/Models/Sensor.cs#L412)

```
[ProtoMember(16)]
public SensorState RawData
{
    get { return _rawData ?? (_rawData =  new SensorState(this, DateTime.Now, new Dictionary<DateTime, float>(), "", true, null)); }
    private set { _rawData = value; }
}
```

[Link](https://github.com/Technicolour/B3/blob/d4f944beada9a7e6a1700eae22cc65ecdadbacff/IndiaTango/IndiaTango/Models/Sensor.cs#L449)

While this works fantastically for when I'm using the properties it messes up serialization processes.

The simple fix was to instead mark the underlying objects for serialization instead.

```
[ProtoMember(16)]
private SensorState _rawData;
[ProtoMember(12)]
private SensorState _currentState;
```

[Link](https://github.com/Technicolour/B3/blob/master/IndiaTango/IndiaTango/Models/Sensor.cs#L36)

Comment: Cool. - thanks for coming back with this extra info. Let me know if you get any other problems.

Answer (score 2):

If `OverwriteList` fixes it, then it suggests *to me* that the dictionary has some data in it by default, perhaps via a constructor or similar. If it is indeed coming from the constructor, you can disable that with `[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor=true)]`.

If I have misunderstood the above, it may help to illustrate with a reproducible example, if possible.

With regard to the ids, they only need to be unique inside each type, and it is recommended to keep them small (due to "varint" encoding of tags, small keys are "cheaper" than large keys).

If you want to really minimise size, I would actually suggest looking at the *content* of the data, too. For example, you say that this is 15 minute readings... well, I'm guessing there are occasional gaps, but could you do, for example:

```
Block (class)
    Start Time (DateTime)
    Values (float[])
```

and have a `Block` for every contiguous bunch of 15-minute values (the assumption here is that every value is 15 after the last, else a new block is started). So you are storing multiple `Block` instances in place of a single dictionary. This has the advantages:

- much less `DateTime` values to store
- you can use "packed" encoding on the floats, which means it doesn't need to add all the intermediate tags; you do this by marking an array/list as  (`[ProtoMember({key}, IsPacked = true)]`) - noting that it only works on a few basic data-types (not sub-objects)

combined, these two tweaks could yield significant savings

If the data has a lot of strings, you could try GZIP/DEFLATE. You can of course *try* these either way, but without large amounts of string data I would be cautious of expecting too much extra from compression.

---

As an update based on the supplied (CSV) data file, there is no inherent problem here handling the dictionary - as shown:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using ProtoBuf;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var data = new Data
        {
            Points =
            {
                {new DateTime(2009,09,1,0,0,0), 11.04F},
                {new DateTime(2009,09,1,0,15,0), 11.04F},
                {new DateTime(2009,09,1,0,30,0), 11.01F},
                {new DateTime(2009,09,1,0,45,0), 11.01F},
                {new DateTime(2009,09,1,1,0,0), 11F},
                {new DateTime(2009,09,1,1,15,0), 10.98F},
                {new DateTime(2009,09,1,1,30,0), 10.98F},
                {new DateTime(2009,09,1,1,45,0), 10.92F},
                {new DateTime(2009,09,1,2,00,0), 10.09F},
            }
        };

        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        Serializer.Serialize(ms, data);
        ms.Position = 0;
        var clone =Serializer.Deserialize<Data>(ms);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} points:", clone.Points.Count);
        foreach(var pair in clone.Points.OrderBy(x => x.Key))
        {
            float orig;
            data.Points.TryGetValue(pair.Key, out orig);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value == orig ? "correct" : "FAIL");
        }
    }
}
[ProtoContract]
class Data
{
    private readonly Dictionary<DateTime, float> points = new Dictionary<DateTime, float>();
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Dictionary<DateTime, float> Points { get { return points; } } 
}
```

Comment: I've already set [ProtoContract(SkipConstructor=true)] but the problem still remains, I've updated my post to link to source and give a raw data file.

Comment: My problem was totally my own, sorry for even hinting otherwise :)